# I Want to replace a value of XLM Using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

```
<property name="country">India</property>
<property name="city">Bangalore</property>
```

I want to search by the key name and if the property name is country. I have to replace the value by Africa and the result should look like below.

```
<property name="country">Africa</property>
<property name="city">Bangalore</property>
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all element with attribute `name="country" to Africa`

Comment: Yes. I want to search with that name and replace the value of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
from lxml import etree as xml
xml_str="""
<note>
<property name="country">India</property>
<property name="city">Bangalore</property>
</note>
"""
xm=xml.fromstring(xml_str)

for a in xm.iter():
    if a.tag == "property" and a.attrib.get("name") == "country":
        a.text = "Africa"
print xml.tostring(xm)
```

**Output:**

```
<note>
<property name="country">Africa</property>
<property name="city">Bangalore</property>
</note>
```

**Notes:**

- I have used lxml to parse and to modify the XML object
  _ I iterate through each element using the for loop
- I check if the element is a `property` element and also if it has a `name` attribute whose value is `country`
- If so then have changed it's value to Africa
- This code is in Python 2.+

Comment: I am using python 2. and it is giving error like below
line 8, in <module>
    xm=lxml.etree.fromstring(xml_str)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'etree'

Comment: @AkhilP could you print dir(lxml)

Comment: @VigneshKalay it is showing error like name 'lxml' is not defined

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: @VigneshKalay python 2.7

Comment: @AkhilP 2.what i am using 2.7

Comment: See if my edit works and @AkhilP try this `import sys;print sys.version` it will tell you the version

Comment: Thank you @VigneshKalai.

Comment: @AkhilP happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

xml_example.xml file

```
<root_1>
    <property name="country">India</property>
    <property name="city">Bangalore</property>
</root_1>
```

**code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("xml_example.xml")
for property in tree.iter('property'):
    if property.attrib['name'] == "country" and property.text == "India":
    property.text = "Africa"
tree.write("xml_example.xml")
```

**Output:**

```
<root_1>
    <property name="country">Africa</property>
    <property name="city">Bangalore</property>
</root_1>
```